# WordPress website in English and Arabic?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed WordPress English version and theme.. now I want the same site in Arabic. Once the user selects Arabic language it must load the arabic version (RTL).

the theme is in LTR. it doesnt support rtl. so I converted the LTR theme into RTL. (css files)
now how can I load the RTL version of the theme when user selects 'Arabic' language. also when he selects 'English' it must load LTR version of the theme..

Answer (score 0):

Have you read below WordPress Multilingual links?

1. [WordPress in Your Language](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language)
2. [Multilingual WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress)